# Django and HTML Dropdown : Populate Parent / Child field with Selected any one of the Child Attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have 3 models which are being used for Dropdown, and user can select value from any of dropdown.
When user select the parent the child dropdown auto-filters (this is working), however need a functionality where, when a user select a child, parent dropdown will also get filter.
While doing research I came across with similar functionality which can be referenced for an example, https://www.hertzcarsales.com/nashville.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=GoogleLocalListing. This is just an example from some existing site.

Due to security reason cannot share actual models (they are not related to Make-Model of cars). however can refer to the above site for example, as this is nearly similar to what I am looking for.

User can select Vehicle Make, and the model + Body Style will auto filter, and when user selects just Body Style, then Make & Model will be filtered accordingly.

For example, in below screenshot I just selected Body Style as Truck, and all Make & Model are auto-filtered.

Please suggest or point me how this can be doable, just a pointer or small suggestion would help.
I did tried using JavaScript, but unable to do reverse dropdown filter.

[image]

Sample Code which I did kind of POC, so that can share, also I knew that having many if..else condition may not be the good practice, but as of now I was able to just demonstrate, what I was looking for:

models.py

```
class VehicleMake(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.make


class BodyStyle(models.Model):
    style = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.style  

class VehicleModel(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    make = models.ForeignKey(VehicleMake, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    style = models.ForeignKey(BodyStyle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        # return self.make.make + ' - ' + self.model + ' - ' + self.style.style
        return self.model


class VehicleColor(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # model = models.ManyToManyField(VehicleModel)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color 

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.ForeignKey(VehicleModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(VehicleColor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mrp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vin + ' - ' + self.model.model + ' - ' + self.color.color
```

Views.py

```
def search(request):

    vmake = VehicleMake.objects.all()
    vmodel = VehicleModel.objects.all()
    vcolor = VehicleColor.objects.all()
    vtype = BodyStyle.objects.all()
    veh = Vehicle.objects.all()
    smake = request.GET.get('vmake')
    smodel = request.GET.get('vmodel')
    stype = request.GET.get('vtype')
    scolor = request.GET.get('vcolor')

    if smake != 'all' and smake is not None:
        print("Search by Make", smake)
        q = VehicleMake.objects.filter(make=smake)
        # print(q)
        veh = veh.filter(model__make__make__in=q.values('make').distinct())

        vmodel = VehicleModel.objects.filter(make__make=smake)
        vtype = BodyStyle.objects.filter(id__in=vmodel.values('style').distinct())

    if smodel != 'all' and smodel is not None:
        print("Search by Model", smodel)
        q = VehicleModel.objects.filter(model=smodel)
        # print(q)
        # print('----')
        # print(veh)
        veh = veh.filter(model__model__in=q.values('model').distinct())

        vmake = VehicleMake.objects.filter(vehiclemodel__model=smodel)
        # print(vmake.query) # to get the sql equivalent
        tmp = VehicleModel.objects.filter(model=smodel)
        vtype = BodyStyle.objects.filter(id__in=tmp.values('style').distinct())

# similar for each combination of Body Type; Make-Model; Make-BodyType; Model-Body Type etc..

    context = {
        'vmake' : vmake,
        'vmodel' : vmodel,
        'vcolor' : vcolor,
        'vtype' : vtype,
        'veh' : veh,
        'smake' : smake,
        'smodel' : smodel,
    }

    return render(request, 'dropdownSearch/search.html', context)
```

HTML page

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dropdown Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Search Cars</h2>

    <!-- <form action="" method="get"> -->
    <form>
        <!-- <input name='ser' type="text"  placeholder="Search by Make-Model-Color"> -->

        <select name="vmake">
            <option value="all">-- All Make --</option>
            {% for rec in vmake %}
            <option value="{{ rec }}">{{ rec }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <select name="vmodel">
            <option value="all">-- All Model --</option>
            {% for rec in vmodel %}
            <option value="{{ rec }}">{{ rec }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        
        <select name="vtype">
            <option value="all">-- All Body Style --</option>
            {% for rec in vtype %}
            <option value="{{ rec }}">{{ rec }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <select name="vcolor">
            <option value="all">-- All Colors --</option>
            {% for rec in vcolor %}
            <option value="{{ rec }}">{{ rec }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <button>Search</button>
        <a href="{% url 'dropdownsearch' %}">Clear</a>
    </form>
    
    <h1>Available Vehicles</h1>
    <!-- {% if smake %} -->
        <!-- Make : {{ smake }}
        Model : {{ smodel }} -->
    <!-- {% endif %} -->
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>VIN</th>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Body Type</th>
            <th>MRP</th>
        </tr>
        {% for rec in veh %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ rec.vin }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.model.make.make }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.model.model }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.color.color }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.model.style.style }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.mrp }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code may not be following the best practices, as this is just a POC, and will be doing more research to make it good.

Comment: Can you share how you are you currently implementing the filters in your views and JS? What security reasons could there be for sharing models of vehicle makes and models?

Comment: Thanks, I have added the view.py; models.py; .html file.